# vertices, edges, polygons etc in polytopes

Tags: geometry, polytopes

I have a problem on N-Dimensional polytopes and their construction using lesser-dimensional polytopes. i have read at this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) that a N-dimensional polytopes has $V$ vertices, $L$ lines, $F$ faces, $C_1$ cubes, $C_2$ tesseracts, and so on. this allows a formula of the form:
(also, the exponents are not exponents, just another subscript type)

$$
\begin{align}
V^1*2&=V^2\\
V^X*2&=V^{X+1}\\
(L^2)\times 2+ V^1&=L^3\\
(L^X)\times 2+ V^{X-1}&=L^{X+1}\\
(F^3)\times 2+ L^2&=F^4\\
(F^X)\times 2+ L^{X-1}&=F^{X+1}\\
({C_1}^4)\times 2+ F^3&={C_1}^5\\
({C_1}^X)\times 2+ F^{X-1}&={C_1}^{X+1}\\
({C_Y}^X)\times 2+ C_{Y-1}^{X-1}&=C_{Y+1}^{X+1}\\
\end{align}
$$

This is the Method I found out from the wikipedia article.  Basically, if you take the $C_{Y}^{X}$ and create another one of $C_{Y}^{X}$, parallel to the first one, and then link the two with $L^{X-1}$ lines, thus creating all the $C_Y$ and less criteria for the link's specifications.

The problem is, i looked on Wikipedia, and there is nothing on the other types of polytopes. can someone show the formula like mine that works for anything involving, starting with the dodecahedron? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The page you'd linked does concern the hypercubes. And it constructs it by dimensional induction as a series of orthogonal prisms, i.e. using the former one as a bottom base and a parallel one as top base, and link those by lacing sides. Then your formula do apply, where your upper index X is nothing but the counter of dimensional induction.

But in fact, such a prismatic series does follow your formula independingly of the starting figure! Thus, the prism of the dodecahedron likewise would follow them. And the prism of the prism of the dodecahedron. Etc.

--- rk

Answer (score 0):

Just as for the prism product, which was the base of both of your own example and my last years answer too, you could derive similar dimensional series for the pyramid product (e.g. simplices) or the tegum product (e.g. orthoplexes) too. - Just confer this [webpage](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/explain/product.htm), where quite similar induction rules are depicted graphically.